# issue including wp_enqueue_media - WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am building a custom interface that is utilizing WordPress functions and a specific area I am trying to utilize is the media section of WordPress.  I am first including the core files of WordPress:

```
$location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wordpress";

include($location.'/wp-config.php');
include($location.'/wp-load.php');
include($location.'/wp-includes/pluggable.php');
global $wpdb;
if( !isset($wpdb) )
{
    include($location.'/wp-config.php');
    include($location.'/wp-includes/wp-db.php');
}
```

Than within my media file I am using: `wp_enqueue_media()` to allow me to access the media viewer for when a user is uploading media from their account.

My `JS` script I am using to run the media request is as follows:

```
$('.add-media').on('click', function( event ){
    var file_frame;
    var wp_media_post_id = wp.media.model.settings.post.id; // Store the old id
    event.preventDefault();

    // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
    if ( file_frame ) {
      file_frame.open();
      return;
    }

    // Create the media frame.
    file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
      title: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_title' ),
      button: {
        text: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_button_text' ),
      },
      multiple: true  // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
    });

    // When an image is selected, run a callback.
    file_frame.on( 'select', function() {

        var selection = file_frame.state().get('selection');

        selection.map( function( attachment ) {

          attachment = attachment.toJSON();
          // Do something with attachment.id and/or attachment.url here

          $(".load-attachments").append('<div class="singleImg"><a href="'+attachment.url+'" class="shadowbox"><img src="'+attachment.url+'" width="100px" height="100px"/></a><input type="hidden" class="fileURL load-single-attachment" value="'+attachment.id+'"/><span class="removeImg remove"> X </span></div>');
          $(".removeImg").bind('click', function(){
             $(this).parent().remove(); 
          });

        });

    });

    // Finally, open the modal
    file_frame.open();
});
```

The issue here is, when running the `add-media` event, `wp` is undefined.  Now I am not sure as to why this is.  Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After looking through documentation, I couldn't really figure out why this was happening.  But I found the solution.  Some final files are called when using `wp_footer()`.  And without this, none of your JavaScript files will run.

So In the future if your developing an application and want to use WordPress core functionalities, make sure to include `wp_footer()` at the end of your application to make sure you won't run into `wp` not being defined in `js`.